# How to implement a basic unit test in javascript for an azure durable function orchestration

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, azure-durable-functions

What would be the unit test which would fake the calls to callActivity in the orchestrator below to return a known value and to expect that the orchestrator returns that value.

The examples on the azure durable functions documentation for unit testing[1] are all written in C# and I've not been able to replicate 
them in javascript despite several attempts. This is because I don't know how to construct an orchestrator with a fake context.

```
  const df = require('durable-functions');

  module.exports = df.orchestrator(function* orchestratorFunctionGenerator(context) {
    const input = context.df.getInput();
    const apimApiName = input.apimApiName;
    const indexNames = yield context.df.callActivity('GetIndexNames', apimApiName);
    const indexerName = indexNames.idle;
    const indexerStatus = yield context.df.callActivity('GetIndexerStatus', indexerName);
    return indexerStatus;
  });
```

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-unit-testing

Comment: I'm leaning towards believing it's not feasible to properly unit test because the Azure durable functions orchestrator uses the JS generator functions and yield to simulate a syntax for asynchronous scope which usually isn't possible. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js/issues/49


It looks like the C# implementation uses asynchronous calls. But in the JS library they chose to go with a generator function and `yield` instead of async functions with `await`.


https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js/issues/5

Answer (score 3):

The approach we went with was to extract the generator method out into it's own module.

```
module.exports = function* orchestratorFunctionGenerator(context) {
  const input = context.df.getInput();
  const apimApiName = input.apimApiName;
  const indexNames = yield context.df.callActivity('GetIndexNames', apimApiName);
  const indexerName = indexNames.idle;
  const indexerStatus = yield context.df.callActivity('GetIndexerStatus', indexerName);
  return indexerStatus;
};
```

then require it

```
const df = require('durable-functions');
const generatorFunction = require('./generator-function');

module.exports = df.orchestrator(generatorFunction);
```

and then test the function in isolation

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const getIndexerStatusOrchestratorGenerator = require('../../GetIndexerStatusOrchestrator/generator-function');

const expect = chai.expect;

function iterateGenerator(generator) {
  let result = generator.next();
  while (!result.done) {
    result = generator.next(result.value);
  }
  return result;
}

describe('getIndexerStatusOrchestrator', () => {
  it('happy path should return \'inProgress\'', () => {
    const indexNames = { active: 'index-1', idle: 'index-2' };
    const apimApiName = 'api';
    const input = { apimApiName };
    const stubCallActivity = sinon.stub();
    stubCallActivity.withArgs('GetIndexNames', apimApiName).returns(indexNames);
    stubCallActivity.withArgs('GetIndexerStatus', indexNames.idle).returns('inProgress');

    const context = {
      df: {
        callActivity: stubCallActivity,
        getInput: sinon.fake.returns(input),
      },
    };

    const generator = getIndexerStatusOrchestratorGenerator(context);

    const result = iterateGenerator(generator);
    expect(result.value).to.equal('inProgress');
  });
  it('indexer status should be for the idle index', () => {
    const indexNames = { active: 'index-1', idle: 'index-2' };
    const apimIndexName = 'api';
    const input = { apimApiName: apimIndexName };
    const stubCallActivity = sinon.stub();
    stubCallActivity.withArgs('GetIndexNames', apimIndexName).returns(indexNames);
    stubCallActivity.withArgs('GetIndexerStatus', indexNames.idle);
    // use stub as a mock since we need both stub and mock behaviour
    // for 'callActivity' and this was the easier option
    stubCallActivity.withArgs('GetIndexerStatus').callsFake((method, indexerName) => {
      expect.fail(`Unexpected indexer name ${indexerName}`);
    });

    const context = {
      df: {
        callActivity: stubCallActivity,
        getInput: sinon.fake.returns(input),
      },
    };

    const generator = getIndexerStatusOrchestratorGenerator(context);

    iterateGenerator(generator);

    // expectations set above
  });
});
```

As might be expected this a trivial example of an orchestrator. We have orchestrators which have considerably more logic in them and where the tests will have more value.

In addition, I personally would not use the mocking approach in the 2nd test and would just rely on testing the outputs using stubs to fake dependency interactions.

Comment: Nice example, but could be much better with some explanation on what is happening. Especially the second test